# in place refreshing of a large tar.gz?

Tags: bash, tar

I have a directory with about 300Mb of code and data, and I need to regularly change a few lines of code in a few of the files and repackage the directory into a new `project-version.tar.gz`. It takes quite a while to repackage all the directory, and I was wondering if there is a way to modify the contents of the few changes done in the existing tar.gz to be able to speed up the process, ideally using a Linux command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-u` (`--update`) (add newer file if it exists) or `-r` (`--append`) to add updated files to the archive. However, this will not work for compressed archives. You do not need to untar your archive, but you have to `gunzip` it first.

Also, `-u` and `-r` flags will not delete the older file from the archive, unless you explicitly state it (with `--delete`).

Side note: I am not exactly sure why you are packaging the source code at all. Maybe you want to use dedicated version control software?